# android facebook connectivity

Tags: android, facebook

i have created a login page for some application in android and i want to one thumbnail containing facebook icon and if i click on that thumbnail small dialog box should appear asking username and password for facebook.

this is my code:

```
package com.conn;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.method.PasswordTransformationMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class j_loginscreen extends Activity
{

    int int_scr_wd;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
try
    {
        setTitle("sourabh");
        TableLayout tlt=new TableLayout(this);
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int_scr_wd= display.getWidth();
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpm = new     LinearLayout.LayoutParams(int_scr_wd,     LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        TableRow tr=new TableRow(this);
        TableLayout tlt1=new TableLayout(this);
        TextView tv=new TextView(this);
        ImageView iv=new ImageView(this);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.login);
        tv.setText("LOGIN");
        tlt1.addView(tv);
        tlt1.addView(iv);

        TableLayout _tlt_login=new TableLayout(this);
        TextView _tv_un_signin = new TextView(this);
        EditText _et_un_signin = new EditText(this);
        TextView _tv_ps_signin = new TextView(this);
        EditText _et_ps_signin = new EditText(this);
        Button _btn_signin=new Button(this);
        Button _btn_frgt=new Button(this);
        _tv_un_signin.setText("USERNAME");
        _tv_ps_signin.setText("PASSWORD");
        _et_un_signin.setText("Enter Username Here");
        _et_ps_signin.setText("Enter Password Here");
        _et_un_signin.setSingleLine();
        _et_ps_signin.setSingleLine();
        _et_ps_signin.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());

        int maxLength = 12;
        InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
        FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
        _et_ps_signin.setFilters(FilterArray);



//          _btn_signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
//          {
//              public void onClick(View v)
//              {
//                  Facebook facebookClient = new Facebook();
//                  facebookClient.authorize(this, "[APP ID]", new String[]     {"publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access"}, this);
//                  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
//                  parameters.putString("message", "Test Photo");
//                  parameters.putString("attachment", "{\"name\":\"My Test     Image\","
//                  +"\"href\":\""+"http://www.google.com"+"\","
//                  +"\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src    \":\""+"http://www.google.com/logos/mucha10-hp.jpg"+"\",\"href\":\""+"http://www.google.com"+"\"}]"
//                  +"}");
//                  facebookClient.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters,    this);
//                  
//              }
//          });



        _btn_signin.setText("SIGN IN..!!!");
        _btn_frgt.setText("Forgot Password???");
        _tlt_login.addView(_tv_un_signin);
        _tlt_login.addView(_et_un_signin);
        _tlt_login.addView(_tv_ps_signin);
        _tlt_login.addView(_et_ps_signin);
        _tlt_login.addView(_btn_signin);
//          _btn_signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
//          {
//              public void onClick(View v) 
//              {
//                  
//                  Intent browserIntent = new     Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com")); 
//                  startActivity(browserIntent);
//              }
//          });
            _tlt_login.addView(_btn_frgt);
        tr.addView(tlt1);
        tr.addView(_tlt_login);

        tlt.addView(tr);


        setContentView(tlt);

    }

catch(Exception error)
    {
        Log.i("login error",error.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

please somebody help me soon.
thanx in advance.

Comment: Please check your post and format it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I am missing the exact question here. I think you know how to create an image that is clickable but you want to create a Facebook login dialog yourself?

The Facebook for Android SDK provides everything you need to work with Facebook's API including the ability to create the login dialogs in Facebook's own style.

I have used this SDK and it works perfectly.
See this link: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android

Comment: hey thanx mullins i got the solution to some extent when i am clicking on my clickable image, a dialog pops up showing facebook as a heading on the top leaving a message "an error occured,please try again" with okay button.....after clicking on "ok" button the login page for facebook is coming..after populating the username and password area progress bar runs and asks for remember password?? after selecting the choice, the progress bar runs again for loading and after some time it stops forever...haha ya its funny..bt please guide me mullins or anyone..